# Can I use GET api when passing authentication token

Tags: api, rest

This is a theoretical question. For some APIs, user need to authenticate themselves and we have authentication token for a user. I feel using GET api is not good idea due to this token.

`/get_data/?user_token=hshhlj8979kjhk&dataid=87979`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's not a good idea, but not due to GET in itself. The real problem is the token as part of the URL and the security problems it creates.

The URL portion of a request is very often cached and logged for auditing or debugging purposes, and having the token there causes it to leak unintentionally.

For example, browsers save your browsing history, and the main portion they record is the URL, so there goes your password to your history, a place it doesn't belongs and is easily exposed accidentally.

Most web servers by default also log the URLs they receive, so again there goes your token. It's quite common for it to end up in logs on web servers, load balancers, intermediate routers and so on, again leaking all over the place.

The solution to this is to strip the token from the URL portion, leaving there only data that's not security-critical. The most common place to put it is in the request's headers. Those are well respected by the HTTP standard and almost never logged or accidentally dumped like the URL.

Of course, all other methods suffer the same. POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS for example, none of them should be ever called with secret data in the URL. Headers provide a "safer" place for that available across all methods. The request body is another common place, but you can't have one in GET, making a header the best alternative.